# How do I use this list as a parameter for this function?

Tags: python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

I'm new to Python and I'm using it to write a Spotify app with Spotipy. Basically, I have a dictionary of tracks called topTracks. I can access a track and its name/ID and stuff with

```
topSongs['items'][0]
topSongs['items'][3]['id']
topSongs['items'][5]['name']
```

So there's a function I'm trying to use:

```
recommendations(seed_artists=None, seed_genres=None, seed_tracks=None, limit=20, country=None, **kwargs)
```

With this function I'm trying to use seed_tracks, which requires a list of track IDs. So ideally I want to input topSongs['items'][0]['id'], topSongs['items'][1]['id'], topSongs['items'][2]['id'], etc. How would I do this? I've read about the * operator but I'm not sure how I can use that or if it applies here.

Comment: Check the updated answer if you are willing to use `*` or `**` operators while calling recommendations() function.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like shown below.

> `ids = [item["id"] for item in topSongs["items"]]`
>
> Here, I have just formed a simple example.

```
>>> topSongs = {
...     "items": [
...         {
...             "id": 1,
...             "name": "Alejandro"
...         },
...         {
...             "id": 22,
...             "name": "Waiting for the rights"
...         }
...     ]
... }
>>> 
>>> seed_tracks = [item["id"] for item in topSongs["items"]]
>>> 
>>> seed_tracks
[1, 22]
>>>
```

#### Imp note about using `*` operator »

`*` operator is used in this case but for that, you will need to form a list/tuple containing the list of data the function takes. Something like

> You have to form all the variables like `seed_tracks` above.

```
data = [seed_artists, seed_genres, seed_tracks, limit, country]
```

And finally,

```
recommendations(*data)
```

#### Imp note about using `**` operator »

And if you are willing to use `**` operator, the **data** will look like

```
data = {"seed_artists": seed_artists, "seed_genres": seed_genres, "seed_tracks": seed_tracks, "limit": limit, "country": country}
```

Finally,

```
recommendations(**data)
```